# My bash script doesn't print the flags

Tags: bash, shell

I am not sure what is wrong with my bash script as it doesn't print the given flags nor it echoes them within case statement:

```
 26 while getopts ":a:b:p:u" opts;
 27 do
 28   case $opts in
 29     a) echo got an A flag;;
 30     b) echo got an B flag;;
 31     u) user=$OPTARGS echo $user;;
 32     p) pass=$OPTARGS echo $pass;;
 33     ?) echo I don\'t know what flag is this;;
 34 esac
 35 done
 36 
 37 echo user: $user pass: $pass
```

This is how I have called it:

```
bash-4.3$ ./functionexample.sh -p 123 -u mona
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed thanks to help from IRC bash channel:

```
26 while getopts ":a:b:p:u:" opts;
 27 do
 28   case $opts in
 29     a) echo got an A flag;;
 30     b) echo got an B flag;;
 31     u) user=$OPTARG; echo $user;;
 32     p) pass=$OPTARG; echo $pass;;
 33     ?) echo I don\'t know what flag is this;;
 34 esac
 35 done
 36 
 37 echo user: $user pass: $pass
```

Comment: I agree quoting is not necessary with variables. But with echo it is suggested you double quote it to prevent undesired behavior. Consider `variable="string spanning two lines"`, `echo $variable` may not produce the result you wish but `echo "$variable"` will :-)  I'll remove the downvote once you make the corrections.

Comment: I'm not questioning your authority in bash as I'm sure you know what you're doing. The test case i have pointed out was perfectly reasonable under the premises of the question and I'm sure that would have been useful for a future reader. A downvote is not a big deal here, I have retracted it already. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
while getopts ":a:b:p:u" opts
do
   case $opts in #removed the dot at the end
    a) echo "got an A flag";;
    b) echo "got an B flag";;
    u) user="$OPTARGS"
       echo "$user"
       #double quote the variables to prevent globbing and word splitting
    ;;
    p) pass="$OPTARGS"
    #Passwords can contain whitespace in the beginning.
    #If you don't double quote , you loose them while storing.
    #eg. pass=$@ will strip the leading whitespaces in the normal case.
       echo "$pass"
    ;;
    ?) echo "I don't know what flag is this" 
    #Better double quote to make echo easy, consider something like \\\\\\
    #count the hashes? eh?
    ;;
   esac
done
```

Comment: Quoting is *not* necessary when assigning variables!

Comment: yes, quoting is not necessary https://www.lynda.com/Bash-tutorials/Working-flags/142989/156661-4.html

Comment: echo in bash is not -e at all. That indentation is wrong, what's the dot you removed? It won't work without : after the "u" Come on!

Comment: I'll remove my downvote and comments once the indentation is correct, the answer works and the stupid comments are removed.

Comment: @Camusensei Quoting might not be needed when assigning one variable to another, but it doesn't hurt either. sjsam is writing about word splitting when passing the variable to a command, in which case quoting matters.

Comment: @andlrc : I believe  double quoting is required here as the the op is trying to store a password  which can contain whitespace in the beginning.

Comment: @Camusensei : I wished to to write `echo in posix` not `echo in bash` Anyway it is irrelevant here ;). Also double quoting is necessary here. See the updated answer.

Comment: @sjsam I don't believe that *not quoting* variable to variable assignments (`def=$abc`) will remove leading and trailing quotes. try: `sh -c 'abc=" hello "; def=$abc; echo "$abc"'` should print `[:space:]hello[:space:]`. And just to clarify, I not arguing about quoting around variable expansions in command. Which should almost always be quoted. Unless you are 100.01% sure they should not be.

Comment: @andlrc Try `./script " password with spaces" ` where `script` is `var=$@;echo "$var"`. This is a corner case though.

Comment: my quote works with no quote. Why would you downvote my answer as well as my question?!

Comment: @MonaJalal : I just downvoted to your answer(not the question) with a comment :( and I am ready to retract it with once you make the changes :)

Comment: As I said my code works what I expect from it. Even the video code is the same as mine!!

Comment: @MonaJalal : Your code works (and I'm glad about it) but that is just a corner case. I just pointed out when it will not work and I believe my finding is reasonable here.

Comment: @sjsam I tried `sh -c 'set " hello" "world ";a=$@; echo "$a"'` and get leading and trailing spaces. Including a space between `hello` and `world`. FTY. my `sh` is symlinked to dash.

Comment: @andlrc : I'm on GNU bash, version 4.2.25.  However, I just noted that  on a korn shell(AJM 93U+) no quotes are needed.