# while looking for matching line 27: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, variables, for-loop

I am trying to create a multiply table using a for loop but I don't know how to initialize the variables and if the read variable needs to be the same in the for loop

```
Syntax:
#!/bin/bash
#multiplication table
#$#=parameter given to the script
#$i=variable in for loop
#$1=variable represents a valid number not zero
#$0=variable represents bash script name

echo "Enter number you want to multiply"
read varnumber
echo "This number: $varnumber has this multiplication result:

if [ $varnumber -eq 0 ]
then
echo "Error - Number missing from command line argument"
echo "Syntax : $0 number"
echo "Use to print multiplication table for a given number"
exit 1
fi

n=$varnumber
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
do
echo "$varnumber * $i = `expr $i \* $varnumber`"
```

Comment: test first at http://shellcheck.net . Good luck. (You need a closing `done` on the `for ... do ...` loop at least).

Comment: Every for loop has to end with "done" which is like a closing tag for the loop

Comment: Thanks guys!  Shellcheck.net check for syntax errors for a given code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A for loop should end with done, so :

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
do
echo "$varnumber * $i = `expr $i \* $varnumber`"
done  #line added
```

Also there is no harm in doing :

```
n="$varnumber"
```

and note that backticks (` `) is not preferred in bash. Use the command `$()` format instead for [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)  reason. So :

```
echo "$varnumber * $i = $(expr $i \* $varnumber)" # Used $() syntax.
```

See what is [obsolete in bash](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).

In fact, much better if you can finish the job without `expr` which is an external command:

```
echo "$varnumber * $i = $((i * varnumber))" # Faster than the previous version
```

(Thanks @benjamin-w for this suggestion)

Comment: Oddly enough, the right-hand-side of an assignment is one place where you actually *don't* need double-quotes around a parameter expansion: neither filename-expansion nor word splitting is performed on the result. (Though it's probably simplest to just have a policy of *always* putting parameter expansions in double-quotes.)

Comment: @ruakh : But there are exceptional cases. See  [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37341022/6379160) and the comments that follow. Unless you're so sure, it is always good to surround variables with double quotes.

Comment: `expr` is an external command, why not just use arithmetic expansion? `echo "$varnumber * $i = $((i * varnumber))"`?

Comment: @BenjaminW.  Why not? Added this stuff :-)

Comment: Good stuff, but the page you link to lists many features that are definitely neither obsolete nor deprecated - the author just opposes them as a matter of _opinion_.
Similarly, the backtick command-substitution syntax is not strictly _deprecated_, although there are good reasons to prefer the `$(...)` syntax, as explained in the [indirectly linked page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082); see the comments on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36732882/45375) for a discussion on whether the backtick syntax is really deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am doing this syntax from now on $() looks like expr is not best way even though it throw the same result.  And you were absulutely right....I was missing - done to end the statement.

Comment: @mklement0 : Yes, not all features in the page i linked are deprecated, but I am inclined to author's preferences in the many cases shown there at the link.

Comment: @mona_sax: That is perfectly fine, as long as you don't misleadingly frame your personal preferences as if the features in question were obsolete or deprecated, as the linked page does in part, unfortunately (as laudable as the effort is in principle); I suggest you at least qualify your link to the page with a warning to that effect (and perhaps give the linked page's author feedback). And, to reiterate the earlier point, `\`...\`` is not strictly _deprecated_ - it just has a better alternative now.

Comment: @mklement0 : Appreciate the f/b. Will make the change :-)

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler bash script to do the above goes like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the number for which the multiplication table is desired."
read varname

if [ $varname -eq 0 ];
then
    echo "Error!! The multiplication of anything with 0 results to 0."
    exit 130        # Exit with CTRL + C
fi

for ((i=1; i<=10; i++)); # You can change 10 into any other number
                         # according to your requirement.
                         # Or substitute it with a variable (say N)
                         # which can be prompted to the user.
do
    product=$(expr $i \* $varname)  # Or use: `expr $i \* $varname`
    echo "$varname times $i = $product"
done
```

The output will look like:

```
"Enter the number for which the multiplication table is desired."
```

If I enter 5 when prompted, the following will be printed:

```
5 times 1  = 5
5 times 2  = 10
5 times 3  = 15
5 times 4  = 20
5 times 5  = 25
5 times 6  = 30
5 times 7  = 35
5 times 8  = 40
5 times 9  = 45
5 times 10 = 50
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I 'll givr it a try this way